# How to configure Shippable to build all projects from single repository?

Tags: git, configuration, server, repository, bitbucket

I have an bitbucket repository with 3 project.

myRepo
  app1(ruby-on-rails)
  app2(node.js)
  app3(node.js)

now I am trying to configure Shippable (https://app.shippable.com/) with this repository to build all this 3 projects and run all tests on them.

I know that I should configure shippable.yml file in the root of my repository, and so far I reached in some certain point of luck what I have you can see here...

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.2.2

env:
  - CI_REPORTS=shippable/testresults COVERAGE_REPORTS=shippable/codecoverage

before_script:
  - cd app1 && mkdir -p shippable/testresults
  - bundle install
  - mvn build

script:
  - rake db:setup
  - cd ../app2 && mvn build
  - cd ../app3 && mvn build
```

My question is how to do it proper way ?

So far I tried to do something like this but there is not luck.

Right now with this script I am getting this error.

```
mvn build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.146 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-21T22:32:28+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/965M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/shippable/workspace/src/bitbucket.org/etibartartu/approot/app1). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I am wondering if any one can have any suggestion how to write .yml file in order to make it work.

the normal flow of building app in Shippable is this.

```
Clone/Pull the project from Github. This depends on whether the minion is in pristine state or not
cd into the workspace
Checkout the commit that is getting built
Run the before_install section. This is typically used to prep your minion and update any packages
Run install section to install any project specific libraries or packages
Run before_script section to create any folders and unzip files that might be needed for testing. Some users also restore DBs etc. here
Run the script command which runs build and all your tests
Run either after_success or after_failure commands
Run after_script commands
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if someone will need it in the future. But I found the solution ...

```
  - cd app1 && mkdir -p shippable/testresults
  - bundle install
  - rake db:setup
  - rails s -p 8081 -b 0.0.0.0 &
```

I forgot basically to put ampersand(&) in the end of the running server so it was running not in background and VM was stuck.